# Pandas deleting row with df.drop doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this (first column is `index` (786...) and second `day` (25...) and `Rainfall amount` is empty):

```
Day Rainfall amount (millimetres)  
786   25                              
787   26                              
788   27                              
789   28                              
790   29                              
791    1                              
792    2                              
793    3                              
794    4                              
795    5
```

and I want to delete the row 790. I tried so many things with df.drop but nothin happend.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: try this: `df = df[df.index != 790]`

Comment: post your code that you claim didn't work, firstly did you assign back the result of `drop`? ie. `df = df.drop(790)`, are you sure the first column is the index? what does `df.index` show?

Comment: if that is not the index then `df[df['Day'] != 790]` will work as `'Day'` is a column and not the index, show the output from `df.info()`

Comment: Yes it is the index. I know my Question is not so clear, but it worked with the code from MaxU.

Comment: Your question is unclear because you didn't include your complete code, stating that a function didn't work does not give a complete picture

Comment: @Madddin, if it's an index, then the EdChum's code: `df = df.drop(790)` should work as well.

Comment: He was right, the code doesn't work.  I ran into the same problem.  It's as one of the answers says, it needs "inplace = true".  In the docs it doesn't say that.  It shows 4 columns a,b,c,d and they use .drop and 2 are gone.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

While dropping new DataFrame returns. If you want to apply changes to the current DataFrame you have to specify `inplace` parameter.

**Option 1**
Assigning back to `df` -

```
df = df.drop(790)
```

---

**Option 2**
Inplace argument -

```
df.drop(790, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Curious why it was decided that an object's method returns another object, while it's more reasonably expected for it to mutate the object itself...

Comment: What you expect is not what other people expect... An argument on the other side is that it can require more reasoning. Using immutable code, the only place where a piece of data can be modified is with an explicit assignment, with mutable operations you can to look at *every* call to a method.

Comment: None of these answers are working and I'm perplexed why. I've merged three CSV files and they mistakenly have the headers copied. After using df.drop() I see that the length of my dataframe correctly decreases by 2 (I have two bad rows of extra headers deep inside). However, attempting to histogram a column throws errors, indicating there's still a phantom row. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

As others may be in my shoes, I'll add a bit here. I've merged three CSV files of data and they mistakenly have the headers copied into the dataframe. Now, naturally, I assumed pandas would have an easy method to remove these obviously bad rows. However, it's not working and I'm still a bit perplexed with this. After using df.drop() I see that the length of my dataframe correctly decreases by 2 (I have two bad rows of headers). But the values are still there and attempts to make a histogram will throw errors due to empty values. Here's the code:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('./summedDF_combined.csv',index_col=[0])
print len(df1['x'])
badRows=pd.isnull(pd.to_numeric(df1['y'], errors='coerce')).nonzero()[0]
print "Bad rows:",badRows
df1.drop(badRows, inplace=True)
print len(df1['x'])
```

I've tried other functions in tandem with no luck. This shows an empty list for badrows but still will not plot due to the bad rows still being in the df, just deindexed:

```
print len(df1['x'])
df1=df1.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
df1=df1.dropna(axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
badRows=pd.isnull(pd.to_numeric(df1['x'], errors='coerce')).nonzero()[0]
print "Bad rows:",badRows
```

I'm stumped, but have one solution that works for the subset of folks who merged CSV files and got stuck. Go back to your original files and merge again, but take care to exclude the headers like so:

```
head -n 1 anyOneFile.csv > summedDFs.csv && tail -n+2 -q summedBlipDF2*.csv >> summedDFs.out
```

Apologies, I know this isn't the pythonic or pandas way to fix it and I hope the mods don't feel the need to remove it as it works for the small subset of people with my problem.