# Problems with drop based on conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
Different_year = df[df['Start_year'] != (df['End_year'])]
```

And i just want to remove that condition from my main dataframe
like this:

df.drop(['Different_year'])

Surprisingly it works but the dataframe still has the same shape

Comment: df[df['Start_year'] == df['End_year']] ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to remove condition from dataframe"? Please, provide some minimal example data with desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas deleting row with df.drop doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481409/pandas-deleting-row-with-df-drop-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Georgy, seems like there's more than one thing wrong with what user is doing. So not exact duplicate unfortunately.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Aha. You are right. I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: So, it looks like it's a duplicate of this question then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression

Comment: @Georgy, agreed, I'll vote to close, but will leave my answer for user to see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression)

Answer (score 0):

The `drop` method does not work in place unless you specify so.

`df.drop(different_year, inplace=True)`

or assign it

`df = df.drop(different_year)`

Make sure your variable `different_year` are indices.

Answer (score 0):

Below solutions should work. Notice the following for Method 1:

- We are feeding the *index* of selected rows into `drop`.
- We assign back to `df` so the dataframe is actually modified.
- `axis=0` represents index-level drop. More information in [`df.drop` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

**Method 1**

```
different_year = df[df['Start_year'] != (df['End_year'])].index

df = df.drop(different_year, axis=0)
```

**Method 2**

```
df = df[~(df['Start_year'] != (df['End_year']))]
```